# AWS Batch jobs killed due because memory requirement == memory limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-batch

In AWS Batch, when I specify a memory requirement of e.g. 32000MB, my job ends up getting killed because (a) the actual instance autoselected has 64GB memory and (b) ECS seems to view 32000MB as both a requirement *and* a hard limit ("If your container attempts to exceed the memory specified here, the container is killed" from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html). So as soon as my job goes slightly above 32GB, it gets killed, even though I am happy for it to use up to the 64GB.

How do I properly specify a minimum memory requirement without causing AWS Batch to kill jobs that go slightly above that? It seems very strange to me that the "memory" parameter appears to be both a minimum and a maximum.

I assume I'm misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 2):

The memory requirements in the `resourceRequirements` property are always the maximum/upper bound. You specify there how much memory at max your job container is going to use.

Quote from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_definition_parameters.html :

> The hard limit (in MiB) of memory to present to the container. If your container attempts to exceed the memory specified here, the container is killed.

A lower/minimum bound would not make much sense, since AWS needs to put your job container onto a host that actually supports the upper bound/limit, because there is no way to tell a priori how much actual memory your container is going to use.

Or put another way: If there were such a thing as a "minimum" requirement and you specified minimum = `1 MiB` and maximum = `16 GiB`, what is AWS Batch supposed to do with this information? It cannot put your job container onto a host with say `512 MiB` of memory because your job container, as it runs, may exceed that, since you said the maximum was `16 GiB` (in this example). And AWS Batch is not going to freeze a running job and migrate it onto another host, once the current host's memory is reached.

The fact that AWS Batch decided to put your concrete job container onto an instance with `64 GiB` may be coincidental because `32 GiB` is just the border of an instance's memory size `32 GiB <-> 64 GiB`. And if your job were to use the full `32 GiB` then there wouldn't be any memory left for the host (without swapping).

Comment: Thank you for this! I have a job that requires a minimum of 32GB of RAM. When I specify 16 cores and 32GB I am provided with an instance with 16 cores and 64GB since none exist with 16 cores + 32GB AFAIK.

At that point, my job sees that its running on a 64GB machine and tries to fully utilize it, but ECS kills it when it goes beyond 32GB. 

However, when I increase the memory requirement to 64GB, I end up with a 128GB instance since that's on the border. So I'm confused about the best way to fully utilize the memory of a 64GB instance without getting upgraded to a 128GB one.

Comment: That's where I'm still confused. If I specify `40 GiB` and am allocated a `64 GiB` instance, and my job uses all memory available to it, it will presumably be killed as soon as it goes above `40 GiB`. I want to use all of the memory available to me on the instance; how can I do that without being leveled up to the next?